# How to get the string which is starting after front slash in Perl regex?

Tags: regex, perl

For example, I have a below string starting with two front slashes. Now I want to get the string  "foo_foo". How do I do that? Thanks in advance.

```
my $str = "// filename : foo_foo";

if ($_ =~ m/^filename\s+:\s+(.+)/) {print "regex $1 \n";}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You populate `$str` but bind the match against `$_`.

Use a different delimiter so you don't have to escape the slashes.

```perl
my $str = "// filename : foo_foo";
if ($str =~ m{^/+\s+filename\s+:\s+(.+)}) {
    print "regex: '$1'\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```perl
my $str = "// filename : foo_foo";
if ($str =~ m{^//\h*filename\s*:\s*(.+)}) {
    print "regex $1 \n";
}
```

See the [online Perl demo](https://ideone.com/RVHSaG). Here, I used `{...}` regex delimiters instead of `/.../` and the pattern looks like `^//\h*filename\s*:\s*(.+)` now, matching

- `^` - start of string
- `//` - a `//` substring
- `\h*` - zero or more horizontal whitespaces
- `filename` - some fixed string
- `\s*:\s*` - a `:` char enclosed with zero or more whitespaces
- `(.+)` - Group 1: one or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible (greedy dot).

Answer (score -1):

Something in line with following sample code should produce desired result.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $str = "// filename : foo_foo";

my($fname) = $str =~ m|// filename : (.*)\z|;

say $fname;
```

Output

```
foo_foo
```